# How does Slurm calculate "MaxRSS" (max memory used by a task)?

Tags: slurm

The [Slurm's documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacct.html) define MaxRss as:

> Maximum resident set size of all tasks in job

Nevertheless, I've performed a series of benchmarks to evaluate the accuracy of this record, and I 've found severe discrepancies between the Slurm's log and the memory registered by the process in the operating system (`/proc/meminfo`).
The experiments have involved 1-process jobs, and the difference registered has been in the order of 10E8.

For this reason, and because the documentation is not descriptive enough, I'd like to know how Slurm calculates the memory of a job.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the accounting comes from /proc/<pid>/statm:

[jobacct_gather (GitHub)](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/ac958d039b60318c305c7d106767560e29a509ee/src/plugins/jobacct_gather/common/common_jag.c)

The stats appears to take the resident memory size and subtract the shared memory. Failures could come from the parsing, subtraction or other problems. I have noticed some discrepancies, but you should file an Issue on GitHub if you can show a reproducible case.